# Dart - How to Check if an optional stream isEmpty and return a widget based on that

Tags: dart, stream, dart-null-safety

What's the best way to set up a ternary expression for an optional list stream (`Stream<List<SubFoo>>?`)?

If there are items in the list, I want to display them in a `StreamBuilder`, but if the list is empty, or the stream property is null, I want to return a different view.

It's optional because my app works as follows:

- Check if there's a `Foo`, if so, subscribe to the stream of `SubFoo` for that `Foo`
- If no `Foo`, wait until the user manually creates one, then subscribe to the stream of `SubFoo`

My widget tree should return one of three views, depending on the data there:

| Has Foo? | Has subFoo? | Widget to be returned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No | No | `NoFooView()` |
| Yes | Yes, but the stream is empty | `NoSubFooView()` |
| Yes | Yes, with active elements | `StreamBuilderView()` |

Here's how I currently have it set, but even when there are items in my `subFooStream` (the third case in the table), the app still shows `NoSubFooView()`:

```
return viewModel.foo == null ? NoFooView() : viewModel.subFooStream?.isEmpty != true ? NoSubFooView() : StreamBuilder(...);
```

Comment: `viewModel.subFooStream?.isEmpty != true` will evaluate to `true` when you have elements in the stream, and also when the stream is `null`. It is `false` when you have non-`null` empty stream. You want to call `isNotEmpty` instead.

Comment: Hey @mmcdon20 - thanks for the info. I'm not able to call `isNotEmpty` - I just have `isEmpty` or `isBroadcast` available. Also, I tried `viewModel.subFooStream?.isEmpty != false` and was getting the same result - still showing the `NoSubFooView()`

Comment: Right, my mistake, I thought the api was like Iterable where you have both `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty`. Looking at the docs, `isEmpty` on Stream returns a `Future<bool>` rather than a `bool` (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-async/Stream/isEmpty.html). You would have to `await` the result before comparing against `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do it as a ternary expression. I wrapped the second if/else condition within my stream builder. If there is a snapshot with data, and the length is greater than 0, it will return the `StreamBuilderView()`, and if not, it will return the `NoSubFooView()`.

```
viewmodel.Foo == null ? NoFooView() : 
StreamBuilder<List<SubFooViewModel>>(
                stream: subFooStream,
                builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null ||
                      snapshot.hasData == false ||
                      snapshot.data?.length == 0) {
                    return NoSubFooView(vm: vm);
                  } else {
                    return StreamBuilderView(...);
                  }
                }),
              ),
```